# sigaction catching SIGALRM

Tags: c

My goal is to make an alarm that goes off every second so that when it is handled by sigaction it prints the time, so each second the new time is printed. I have a loop in the middle of this code that counts to a random number but I took that out to make this code more condensed and easier to look at because I believe the problem is with how I'm using sigaction, because it prints multiple times for one second but I just need one line of output for this second.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void alarmPrint(int signum);

time_t curtime;

int main(){

  printf("Enter ^C to end the program:\n");

  struct sigaction sig;

  sig.sa_handler = alarmPrint;

  int count;

  int final;

  time(&curtime);

  srandom(curtime);

  while(1){

    time(&curtime);

    alarm(1);

    printf("\n");

    if(sigaction(SIGALRM, &sig, 0) == -1){

      printf("Error\n");

    }

  }

  return 0;

}


void alarmPrint(int signum){

  printf("current time is %s\n", ctime(&curtime));

}
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: Note this typo `time_t cur time;` Should be time_t curtime;

Comment: Is this how sigaction is correctly used when catching a SIGALRM signal, the way I understand it is that saying alarm(1) means SIGALRM will be sent in 1 second which sigaction will catch and then call alarmPrint which then prints the current time, therefore for every second that this program runs the time will be printed. However currently it is printing more than one time per second which is where my question comes in, is sigaction and alarm being correctly used for that desired output?

Comment: You should move the sigaction outside of the loop, you are registering the same signal handler many times.

Comment: Well with the code right now, which is the same code as above, now it doesn't print anything, so is there some reason my sigaction call isn't calling my function to print the date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have pointed out.

You should move your sigaction outside of the loop and also the alarm.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void alarmPrint(int signum);

int main(){

  int count;
  int final;

  printf("Enter ^C to end the program:\n");
  signal(SIGALRM, alarmPrint);
  alarm(1);

  while(1) {
    /* do other stuff here */
  }

  return 0;

}

void alarmPrint(int signum){
  time_t curtime;

  time(&curtime);
  printf("current time is %s", ctime(&curtime));
  alarm(1);

}
```

You also need to reset the alarm inside of your `alarmPrint()` function so it will go off in another second.

Lastly `ctime()` already includes a new line, so you don't need one when printing the time.